# BizTalk: Visual Studio Hangs on Map Validation

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

I've created a basic map in BizTalk. No connections have been made. My input schema is a file within the same solution but in a separate project. The output schema is from a referenced .dll file (it is a very big schema).

When I go to build my project file, VS hangs (isolated this to the newly created map). When I go to validate my newly created map it will hang on `invoking component...`.

I have checked the Windows logs and looked for error dumps but no such luck, just a simple `devenv.exe stopped interacting...`

I can't find any reference to this issue. Does anyone have any ideas or have encountered this issue?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**
I have isolated the issue to the referenced .dll schema that I have within my project. If I replace the schema with another referenced or local schema it will work just fine. I do not have the ability to edit this particular referenced schema unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when a Default Value is set either in the Schema or Map anywhere in a *recursive* structure.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What if I do no have access to the schema, thus I cannot change the default Value setting? I have isolated my issue to the huge schema that I am referencing via a .dll. Is it possible that the schema is simply too large for the BT mapper to handle?

Comment: I think my issue is that the schema is already deployed and referenced in another application and I use it with a mapper twice.

Comment: No, being referenced multiple times is not a problem.  What do you consider 'large'?

Comment: Ha, good question. In my terms it's 'big'. We're only talking `190kb`.

Comment: 190KB?  That's barely measurable ;).  Large doesn't begin until 2.5MB.